# jquery seesion destroy the object once the page redirected to another html page?

Tags: jquery

I have 5 HTML page, I would like to manage the session state using jquery. Here my question is, if i redirect to another page whether the session variable get destroyed or not (here i am redirecting to another page using anchor tag)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, however session state is governed server-side, so jQuery would have no direct control over it, being client-side. You could use AJAX onUnload, however it probably wouldn't work very well.

Comment: [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580172/session-handling-in-jquery) talks about session usage with query, as Session is independent from pages, session varialble won't be destroyed, I guess

Comment: Hi asdf_enel_hak , I would like to store my activex control in jquery session state variable and can i use that objects across the web page?