# How to assign session variable in java script in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0

Actually i need a functionality like i want to assign a session variable in java script ...when i researched so many people said we cant do it but in some blogs i found we can assign and we can get.....here below are the links that they said possible

[How to access Session variables and set them in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-can-i-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript)

http://shekharshetemcts.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/how-to-access-session-variables-using-javascript-in-asp-net/comment-page-1/#comment-294​

but my problem is when i am using that code i am getting an error like  below

Error:-The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. ).

Below is my javascript code

```
function showorhide(id) {
    if (document. getElementById (id).style.display == "none") {
    document. getElementById (id).style.display = "block";
    var idA = id;
    if (idA == "workdiv3") {
        var id = "10";
        '<%Session["x"] = "' + id + '"; %>';

        alert('<%=Session["x"] %>');
    }
    } 
else {
    document . getElementById (id).style.display = "none";
    var idA = id;
    if (idA == "workdiv3") {
        var id = "11";
        '<%Session["x"] = "' + id + '"; %>';

        alert('<%=Session["x"] %>');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We need to see your actual code, what you made of those links.

Comment: we need to see your code

Comment: Sir i updated my code in my question.  please see the above code.

Comment: @user1919099 your code is looking fine but i hope you have code block problem so refer this link it my useful to you.http://stackoverflow.com/a/1176779/2798643

Comment: Please check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25997455/3991984

Hope it helps.