# Populate HTML listbox using javascript function on page load

Tags: javascript, html, listbox

I have a HTML Listbox and I need to add values to it on the page load. I have tried to call a JS function on page load event on both `<body>` tag and `<select>` tag but it does not execute the the function.

```
<body onload='popListbox(<%=session.getAttribute("objNames")%>)'>

<select id="lstObjects" onload='popListbox(<%=session.getAttribute("objNames")%>)'>
```

If I try `onclick` it executes fine but not in `onload` event. Can someone help me with this.?

**UPDATE:** my JS function

```
function popListbox(objList){

var select = document.getElementById("lstObjects");
var objects = objList;
var objects_array = [];
for(var i in objects) {
    if(objects.hasOwnProperty(i) && !isNaN(+i)) {
        objects_array[+i] = objects[i];
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < objects_array.length; i++) {
    var opt = objects_array[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try document.ready

$( document ).ready(function() {

//your code here

});

Comment: If I use this method how can I pass the parameter I'm passing in my popListbox() method.?

Comment: var objNames = '<%= Session["objNames"] %>'

Comment: u can use that variable as your parameter

Comment: there are alot of ways which will help you to access values from your session using javascript and jquery

Comment: it takes all inside single quotes as string value. is there any other way.? :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-can-i-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript

Comment: Yes it works when I'm writing the JS function in same html page. but I'm using seperate JS file to write JS functions so single quating and accessing sessions variables does not work any more. thats why I had to use a parameter to pass values to JS function in the 1st place. But when I do that I cant use $document.ready(); method.

Comment: Finally I decide to use JS in same HTML page. thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score -1):

What's the JS function?
I suspect, because only the body tag has an onload handler, perhaps your js function is not aware of the element context when it is triggered from document root.

```
function popListbox(objList){
var select = document.getElementById('lstObjects');
for(i=0,ic=objList.length;i<ic;++i) {
    var el=document.createElement('option');
    el.textContent=objList[i];
    el.value=objList[i];
    select.appendChild(el);
}
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work but I rewrote it because it's the same result

Comment: I have added my JS function. please look into it.