# pass Script attribute at run time

Tags: javascript, c#

I have to charge from  Stripe payment gateway, and code also available on website, but it only take hard code value. I want to apply `data-amount` attribute value at runtime which came from session from another page which is taken from enduser from textbox from another page.

```
<div>
    <form action="Default.aspx" method="post">
        <script
         src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" class="stripe-button"
         data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
         data-amount="2000"
         data-name="Demo Site"
         data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
         data-image="/128x128.png"
         data-locale="auto">
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Just replace data-amount attributes which value is 2000 with run time value from session or query string.

Comment: If you are using razor check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538834/get-current-session-value-in-javascript if not maybe try jquery session: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580172/session-handling-in-jquery

Comment: A recomendation, if you can, use a custom form, do the payment process on the server side and use the Stripe library directly, it's safer and you will have full control of the process