# multi language using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization

I have 3 different languages in my website. I would like to create 3 buttons for changing relative language:

- Clicking `Eng` will direct to /en/index.html
- Clicking `Chinese` will direct to /../chi/index.html
- Clicking `japan` will direct to /../jp/index.html

```html
<a class="changeLang" href="chi">CHI</a>
<a class="changeLang" href="eng">ENG</a>
<a class="changeLang" href="jp">JP</a>
```

Is it any simple javascript to change the page? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript? Just make it a link with the specified href

Comment: place exactly what you said in the href of each language

Comment: Because I need to change language every page.

Comment: I guess you can set a cookie and use that to redirect on the server side to a specific language

Comment: as far as i understand the locale pages should be relative to current page (so user can be taken from a page to the exact same page but in different locale)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get informations from your previous Javascript page..
When you reload it, your variables are deleted.

If you want to get information and use it between pages, you can use $_SESSION or $_COOKIE from PHP.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-can-i-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript).

Good luck !

Comment: as far as i understand the locale pages should be relative to current page (so user can be taken from a page to the exact same page but in different locale)