# Asp.net mvc set session variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am trying to set session value in javascript :

```
//session value 5400
//remainingSeconds value 5399
@Session["remain-seconds"] = remainingSeconds;
```

But i am getting the following error:

> invalid left-hand side in assignment

Is it possible to set session variable inside javascript?

Comment: Sessions cannot be accessed by JavaScript

Comment: @jasonwarford  Are you sure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, session variables are server side. You'd have to have a little ajax call to talk to the server to set it. There are plenty of examples of this via google searches. [You can see one example here.](http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2015/01/05/getset-value-session-variable-using-javascriptjquery/)

For a one-time evaluation (on the server, before it hits the client), you can set it (sort of) in the code section of your script, but I think that's different from what you're asking to do. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-can-i-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript).

Comment: I am using setinterval to implement countdown timer. It would be heavy process to send ajax request in every second.  I did it because  user can change javascript variable from console and i need unchangable global variable in javascript

Comment: There's options for that sort of thing. Session isn't one of them.  =) Please open a new question for recommendations on ways to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: Okey i found solution, simple wrap inside (function(){  : )))