# accessing session variables from code behind in javacscript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, session

I have set the session variable in backend(code behind ascx.cs page)  where i want to access the same value in checkbox checked event in javascript ..

this is my code in javascript function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= gvPRCertInfo.ClientID %> input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {

        var background1 = null;
        background1 = '<%= Session["FriendlyData"] %>';
        alert(background1); // i am getting this value 'system.data.dataset'
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var signValue = 
     $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(4)').html();

        }
    });
 });
```

This variable **<%= Session["FriendlyData"] %>**  is a dataset and i have assigned some values in backend, now  i want to access the same value in above js function

when i put alert  I am getting value as **System.data.dataset** and i am not getting what is the value in session..

Could any one please help on how to get the dataset value in javascript function...

many thanks in advance

Comment: see this post if it helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-to-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify your codeback object in some way. For example,

```
//.aspx.cs
DataSet ds = GetMyDataSet();
Session["dataset"] = ds;

//.aspx
<script>
var ds = '<%=((DataSet)Session["dataset"]).GetXml()%>';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support .. i have used hidden variable to get this done

Comment: @EnigmaState You can accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Sorry i did not use your solution .. i made it one hidden variable and i assigned value in code behind, accessed it in javascript file

Comment: Code behind is the best solution. In such cases I use `var a = '<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrJsVal" />';` (and set `.Text` in codebehind). The question is *did I answer the OP?*