# How to set JavaScript variable to ASP.NET Session?

Tags: javascript, c#

How can I set a JavaScript variable to an ASP.NET Session? Currently the value in the price is not stored in the session, instead it stores the string "'+price+'". How to store the price variable's value?

```
function getCheckboxVal(el)
{
    var price = el.getAttribute("Price");
    '<%Session["Price"] = "' + price +'"; %>';
}
```

Comment: Why using JS to set that session variable?

Comment: Session variables are set and maintained on the server. You cannot access them directly with JavaScript. To set / get the value of a Session variable in JavaScript you would need to use an AJAX call to the server to a script that sets / gets the value and returns it to the JavaScript code.

Comment: no its not @JohnB you can access it in the javascript

Comment: @HamzaHaider just to confirm are you saying it is possible to access session variables `directly` from javascript?

Comment: yes it is. We don't need to send ajax call

Comment: Who have confusion Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-to-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript

Comment: @HamzaHaider - i'd be keen to see a sample of that - got a link to example?

Comment: @HamzaHaider just seen your link.  if you read it carefully it supports `my` argument.  you are left where you started - wrong.

Comment: @JohnB You cannot access them directly with JavaScript. To set / get the value of a Session variable in JavaScript you would need to use an AJAX call to the server to a script that sets / gets the value and returns it to the JavaScript code... This is wrong statement according to the link

Comment: @HamzaHaider - no the answer is wrong and others comment to that affect.  someone has just answered below to also that same affect.  read this carefully - `You can not directly set session from JS because session is stored on server and js is client side`.  this is a fact - sorry to disagree but i'm surprised people get so confused over client-side and server-side.

Comment: @JohnB  It is astonishing for me that you talked about ajax call and now you are changed

Comment: ajax is a way to set something server side.  the answer below is using another technique to set values on controls.  none of this detracts from the fact you were incorrect. trying to deflect the argument onto something else is futile.  i stand by my first comment `Session variables are set and maintained on the server. You cannot access them directly with JavaScript. `

Comment: First the server works on that text (it is not seen as JavaScript yet) and processes those ‘<% >‘ parts. *Then* it is sent to the server and treated as JavaScript. Inspect the source in the browser to see

Comment: @HansKeﬆing - sorry hard to follow you but all good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not directly set session from JS because session is stored on server and JS runs at client side.

You can use hidden inputs for this purpose like:

```
<input  type='hidden' id='Price' name='Price'/>

var price = el.getAttribute("Price"); //Populate price var as required
var h=document.getElementById('Price'); 
h.value=price; //set hidden input's value
```

Then get this `var price` to set the session from code behind like:

```
Session["TestSession"] = Request.Form["Price"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `Session` state maintained on server-side, it can't be assigned directly from client-side. You can perform an AJAX callback to a server-side web method which later stores session state value:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void SetPrice(string value) 
{
    if (Session != null)
    {
        Session["Price"] = value;
    }
}

function getCheckboxVal(el) {
    var price = el.getAttribute("Price");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Page.aspx/SetPrice',
        data: { value: price },
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        }

        // other AJAX settings
    });
}
```

Or using hidden field with `runat="server"` attribute and assign its value to bring it into code-behind:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenPrice" runat="server" />

<script>
    function getCheckboxVal(el) {
        var price = el.getAttribute("Price");

        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenPrice.ClientID %>').value = price;
    }
</script>
```

**Code behind**

```
Session["Price"] = HiddenPrice.Value.ToString();
```

Reference: [Accessing & Modifying Session from Client-Side using JQuery & AJAX in ASP.NET](https://kalpeshshirodker.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/accessing-session-from-javascript-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net/)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot directly set clientside value to session. We can do this by using Hidden fileds

```
<asp:HiddenFieldID="hdPrice" runat="server" />
```

Further get this js price and set to variable hprice in javascript.
This variable can be added into session

```
Session["PriceData"] = hdPrice;
```

Hope this helps you.