# Is it possible to create new session with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I am working on a Java web application which involves certain server side resources being allocated in a per session basis, and such allocation is marked as a session attribute. In order to facilitate a new feature, it is required to each page a different session, i.e. they shall not share the same session. Right now this has to be done by asking the user to explicitly create new session in their browsers or change its configuration. Is it possible to implemented with javascript or jQuery such that a new window is displayed with a different session every time? If javascript or jQuery cannot achieve such effect, any other alternative? The server side does not need to know the new session ID or anything related to it, and the primary client browser would be IE (version 8 or newer) so it does not matter if the solution is browser dependent.

All I am asking is to achieve the same effect as the following, without having the users actually do so:

[image]

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257631/how-create-a-session-using-javascript

Comment: or if you are using jQuery, there is a [plugin for cookies](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

Comment: Have you looked at [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)?

Comment: None of the pointers above answer the question.  The links tell how to deal with sessions, not how to make the browser create a new one.