# Using javascript to send an object through a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I'm stuck trying to pass an object to another page , using javascript.
I hope you can give me a hand . Thanks.

Here the object created and sent through a form and input.

```
var cars = {nombre : "luis", apellido: "heya"};

var form = '<form action="RegisterOrder.php" method="post">'+'<input type="hidden" name="arrayDatosProductos" value="'+cars+'"></input>'+'</form>';
$(form).submit();
```

In the page that receives the object :

```
var a = new Object(<?php echo $_REQUEST['arrayDatosProductos']; ?>);
alert(a.nombre);
```

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257631/how-create-a-session-using-javascript) addresses how to use cookies with JavaScript. Make sure you're not passing any sensitive info around with JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript

```
var cars = {nombre : "luis", apellido: "heya"};

var form = '<form action="RegisterOrder.php" method="post">'
    + '<input type="hidden" name="arrayDatosProductos" value="'
    + String( JSON.stringify(cars) )
    + '"></form>';
$(form).submit();
```

PHP

```
var a = <?= $_REQUEST['arrayDatosProductos']; ?>;
alert(a.nombre);
```

I am not sure about the jQuery stuff, submitting a form created in JavaScript, but you need to convert the object `cars` to JSON and have it echoed in PHP into the new variable.

Comment: Thanks, but when I get in php I only get "{" should use a for or something?. I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after several attempts I could solve my problem , the last was by quotation marks (""), well, I stay this way :

```
var cars = {nombre : "luis", apellido: "heya"};
var ll = JSON.stringify(cars);

var form = '<form action="RegisterOrder.php" method="post">'
+'<input type="text" name="arrayDatosProductos" value='
+String(ll)+'></input>'+'</form>';

$(form).submit();
```

Y por ultimo:

```
var a = <?php echo $_REQUEST['arrayDatosProductos']; ?>;
alert(a.nombre);
```

I hope it will help someone in the future :)