# How to create session with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a PHP code like this to create session:

```
Session::toast('sessionname', 'sessionvalue');
```

and than for calling session like this:

```
if (Session::tersedia('sessionname')) { 
  echo "<div class='notif-merah animNotif'>"
    .Session::toast('sessionname')
    ."</div>"; 
}
```

How to create session with JavaScript?

Comment: what does javascript have to do with anything here ?

Comment: Look at the `sessionStorage` API :/

Comment: Javascript uses cookies .. create cookies like jQuery.cookie or use browser local storage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a session using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257631/how-to-create-a-session-using-javascript)

Comment: I want to replace the above php create session with the java script language so it can be called with the php language below? can it be?

Comment: Remember that PHP sessions data is stored on your server, Javascript session data is, by definition, stored in the browser of the client. This means you should not store sensitive information using Javascript sessions.

Comment: Seems OP is confused about the difference between client side and server side programming

Comment: seems OP has no idea about what a session is

Comment: Session is only used for a notification, when I use java language to insert data, I have trouble in making session notification code like php language above

Answer (score 1):

The client side are usually scripts that run on the browser, like JavaScript. You should not store sensitive data on the client side. Instead, store sensitive session data on the server by using PHP's associative array [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). PHP and the browser will take care of handling sessions for you, normally by [using cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).