# how to set php Cookies for long period of time

Tags: php

how to maintain the cookies for a long duration of time even if the user logout from the site and when user login next time the earlier set of cookies should be there

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532635/javascript-cookie-with-no-expiration-date

Answer (score 0):

If you just want cookies that experiences after a given duration you just use that:

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

where `expire` can be for example `time()+60*60*24*$days`.

Comment: he wants cookie that has no expiration date or very long expiration date, so it is no help.

Comment: Maybe, but that's not clear at all... 'for a long duration of time even if the user logout from the site and when user login next time the earlier set of cookies should be there', nothing is said about 'no expiration date'...