# jQuery: Set cookie time to unimited

Tags: jquery, jqxwidgets

I am using following code bt its not wokring:-

```
var newdate = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)); //expire after 30 days
$.jqx.cookie.cookie('cookieName', true, { expires: newdate});
```

I am using jQWidget to set the cookie.

Comment: Formatting, language

Comment: You Cant, Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641737/how-to-set-this-cookie-to-never-expire

Comment: @vinay is it possible to set cookie time for all jquery cookie at once for different name of cookies .
like we have set cookie1 ,cookie2,... but want to set there expire time once?