# Session only cookies with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it's possible to create session only cookies with Javascript. When the browser is closed the cookies should be removed.

I can't use anything on the server as the website is HTML only ... so no server side script is used.

I read something about this here:
http://blog.lysender.com/2011/08/setting-session-only-cookie-via-javascript/
but i can't find any more information about this ... so i was wondering if this method is reliable.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Not putting an `expires` part in will create a session cookie, whether it is created in JavaScript or on the server.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/532660/1901857

For the use case in the question (no server side code), `sessionStorage` is a simpler solution. But `sessionStorage` is client only, so would not work if you need to access the stored value on the server (e.g. user logins etc.)

Comment: It does not work for me and tried in many ways... Maybe this answer is outdated.

Comment: @Dan Session cookies doesn't work in case of enabled config: "Continue where you left off" in browser. In that cases browsers will not destroy session cookies after closing.

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan you are right but you have to ask all the users of your website to disable the config "Continue where you left off". Instead sessionStorage worked straight away in all the browsers.

Comment: @Rhumborl also, sessionstorage is limited to the current tab, whereas a session cookie is valid for the whole browser session

Answer (score 55):

A simpler solution would be to use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage), in this case:

```
var myVariable = "Hello World";

sessionStorage['myvariable'] = myVariable;

var readValue = sessionStorage['myvariable'];
console.log(readValue);
```

However, keep in mind that `sessionStorage` saves everything as a string, so when working with arrays / objects, you can use JSON to store them:

```
var myVariable = {a:[1,2,3,4], b:"some text"};

sessionStorage['myvariable'] = JSON.stringify(myVariable);
var readValue = JSON.parse(sessionStorage['myvariable']);
```

> A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.

So, when you close the page / tab, the data is lost.

Comment: Yes, Session storage is the best choice for this use casE.

Comment: actually now i am using session storage ... but apparently when you open a new tab in chrome and firefox you can't access the stuff you stored in the session storage ... so that's why i was looking at session cookies: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165452

Comment: In that case, the cookies should be reliable, although I have no idea how well-supported they are.

Comment: Session (and Local) storage are affected by Same-Origin-Policy, so if you switch from http to https, you do not have access to the stuff stored in http (and visa-versa)

Comment: I think `SessionStorage` only provides a `client-only` solution without any access to these values on server-side. In many server-side frameworks like ASP.Net and PHP, we would like to easily access the client-side values that we may have stored without using hidden fields etc., and then cookies become a better solution since cookies get automatically sent to the server-side.

Comment: that's far from simpler, especially when there's cases in which it won't work. Then you throw in JSON also. This is simple: document.cookie = 'cookiname=cookievalue; path=/; domain=google.com; ';

Comment: What isn't simpler, is to get a complex value from that cookie. JSON stringify / parse is a piece of cake, compared to that.

Comment: SessionStorage is awesome, but also currently broken for iOS Safari in Private mode (or with some security settings set incorrectly). Not sure if it's broken by a design decision on Apple's part though. (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/01/23/ios-private-browsing-localstorage/)

Comment: @strah: How did that edit make the quote better, in any way?

Comment: @Cerbrus: because someone reading your answer (and not knowing a difference between session cookies and sessionStorage) can get impression that a "session" will always behave in the same way, whereas in fact session cookies will persist between tabs/windows from the same domain, so updating the quote would make your answer complete.

Comment: @strah: Not without explaining _how_ the behaviour is different.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Your answer is good. My edit was a suggestion how to make it even better :-) IMHO, it *might be* a bit confusing now, but I don't insist, it's your answer.

Comment: data cant be retrieved from session storage if there is new redirection to a different page.

Answer (score 13):

For creating session only cookie with java script, you can use the following. This works for me.

```
document.cookie = "cookiename=value; expires=0; path=/";
```

then get cookie value as following

```
 //get cookie 
var cookiename = getCookie("cookiename");
if (cookiename == "value") {
    //write your script
}

//function getCookie        
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Okay to support IE we can leave "expires" completely and can use this

```
document.cookie = "mtracker=somevalue; path=/";
```

Comment: expires=0 in IE doesn't set a cookie at all: http://blog.lysender.com/2011/08/setting-session-only-cookie-via-javascript/

Comment: expires="" works in IE, and allows you to reset the expiry of a cookie to Session, if you have explictly set it

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code for a setup session cookie, it will work until browser close. (make sure not close tab)

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }
  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  
  if(getCookie("KoiMilGaya")) {
    //alert('found'); 
    // Cookie found. Display any text like repeat user. // reload, other page visit, close tab and open again.. 
  } else {
    //alert('nothing');
    // Display popup or anthing here. it shows on first visit only.  
    // this will load again when user closer browser and open again. 
    setCookie('KoiMilGaya','1');
  }
```

Comment: No, setting an expire date is what not makes it a browser session cookie