# Internet Explorer won't let me create session cookie using this Javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I am creating cookies using Javascript as below

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

While Firefox and Chrome create a **mcoo** cookie for 7 days and **mdes** cookie for SESSION, Internet Explorer creates only the **mcoo** cookie. What am I missing here?

```
    createCookie('mcoo', hash, 7);
    createCookie('mdes', hash);
```

**Update**

As a workaround I have changed the days * 24 to 6, and changed the expiration day of mcoo to 28 (so this is 1 week) and put an expiration daty to mdes 1 (6 hours). But I want per session.

Comment: your `expires` variable is being set within the `if` and `else` blocks.  They are out of scope when you are trying to create the cookie (`undefined`).

Comment: @ps2goat Eh.. no.  JavaScript's `var` is function-level scope, not block level.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, I see.  Doesn't it still make sense to declare a variable at the top before going into the if blocks, if the variable is scoped and used throughout the function?

Comment: @ps2goat Those words start religious wars, fire and brimstone... but I will say that many would agree with you including the venerated or hated Douglas Crockford.

Answer (score 4):

As you find out... IE work's different (again, extrange eh?)

giving a `ZERO` value to expire, will just work as expected in `firefox`& `chrome` but not in `IE` because in `IE`, the cookie will expire immediately as soon as it is set.

So...

#### FF & CR:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + " expires=0; path=/";
```

...To make this work in `IE`, you need to remove the `expire` parameter and leave just like this:

#### IE:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + " ; path=/";
```

#### *Update*

I will probably use something like:
<sup>*edit: tested and working on IE11 && CR36*</sup>

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {

    var c_date,
    c_name = name + "=" + value + ";",
    c_expi = "",
    c_path = "path=/";

    if (days > 0) {
        c_date = new Date();
        c_date.setTime(c_date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        c_expi = "expires=" + c_date.toGMTString() + ";";
    }

    // create the cookie
    document.cookie = c_name + c_expi + c_path;

}
```

Then, call the function:

```
// normal cookie expire in 7 days
createCookie('mcoo', hash, 7);
// session cookie
createCookie('mdes', hash, 0);
```

---

<sub>Source: [Setting Session Only Cookie via JavaScript](http://blog.lysender.com/2011/08/setting-session-only-cookie-via-javascript/)</sub>
<sub>More: [Session only cookies with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196671/session-only-cookies-with-javascript)</sub>

Comment: I see, thank you. How can I change my code in order to allow me set cookies for 7 days and session cross browsers?

Comment: Use the one for `IE` for all... giving no `expire parameter`, will make a `session cookie`

Comment: Oh! look what I found, same explanation & same source XD... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196671/session-only-cookies-with-javascript

Comment: but if I replace the current with the IE suggestion, how can I create cookies with 7 days expiration?