# New tab opens login page even though already logged in another tab

Tags: javascript, session, backbone.js, authentication, frontend

I am new to web development and I am trying to implement *log in* functionality. I have successfully implemented the log in functionality. When I open `www.bla.com/login` I am able to log in post which gets redirected to the homepage.

Problem: If open another tab and type: `www.bla.com/login` it again opens login page. Ideally if I am logged into one of the tab, I should be redirected to homepage irrespective the url being pointed to login page.

P.S: I am not sure what chunk of code I need to share here because I am not sure what causes this issue. Please help or let me know if I need to post my code base. I am using JavaScript and backbone as front end.

**EDIT**

I have a REST Service which gets hit when I login and REST service gives me back a User Specific Token. I use this user specific token to again call another Rest Service to fetch more user specific data.

So, basically I need to put a check on this token received. The token received I have stored in browser session. But when I go to another tab and try to access that token its NULL. So I am assuming every tab in browser does not share the session storage. If Yes, then where shall I place this Token so that if someone hits the login page I should check whether a token already exists. if exists then redirect to home page. Kindly guide.

Comment: You can store a login token in a cookie, and check for the cookie on the login page, if the cookie is there you can redirect them to the homepage. Make sure to set a shorter expiry date for the cookie though.

Comment: @StevenTang: Since I am new to all this. Can you point me to any link or any elaborate suggestions. Many Thanks!

Comment: This link should help. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @StevenTang : I have made one edit. Can you kindly look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing your code, so let me make an educated guess:

Most likely you do not create cookie with some sessionId after user is successfully logged in.
This cookie would be then used in every request sent to the server, to prove that user is indeed authenticated.

When you open a new tab and there is no cookie/session created, than this new instance of application has no knowledge of the other instance, where user is already logged in.

You may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196671/session-only-cookies-with-javascript)

**EDIT**

Maybe you are using `sessionStorage` instead of `cookies`. At least I would say so, when I read about behaviour of your app.

See the [docs for session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage
>   object. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only
>   difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set,
>   data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends.
>   A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window
>   will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how
>   session cookies work.

So make sure that you application store the token either in `cookies` or in `localStorage`. And also that it correctly reads from them. Maybe the cookies is created, but never read?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have made one edit in the question can you kindly look into it.

Comment: @Unbreakable Ok, I have updated my answer as well :)

Comment: Can you look into it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358556/how-to-save-token-and-pass-it-to-new-tab-while-opening-new-tab-login-issue