# How to pass token to new tab in same browser (Login Issue)

Tags: javascript, session, web, authentication

I am learning web development and implementing the login functionality. I have a rest service which generates a unique token for each user which logs in. Now I had one issue if I log in one tab and go to homepage and if I go to another tab, instead of getting redirected to home page I was getting redirected to log in page again in the new tab. Ideally, if I go to another tab I should get redirected to home page. It happened because I was saving unique token in session storage. But I realized that session storage is per tab basis so now I am saving the token received from Rest service in local storage.

Below is what I did:

Before `redirecting to login page` I am checking if `token exist` in `local storage`

```
 if((localStorage.getItem('p_kt')))
 window.location = "pages/firstDashboard.html";
```

If token does not exists normal login code runs and I get the token from REST Service

```
localStorage.setItem('p_kt', self.get('tokenProp'));
```

Also, when some one logs out I do:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

So everything seems to be working now. But I doubt its the right way to fix the issue. Can someone guide me. Is it okey to keep token in local storage.

Comment: someone please help.

Comment: Look at these discussions about security and localStorage, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718349/html5-localstorage-security