# Browser window specific variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to store a specific value for each browser window.
This value should stay the same after a reload.

**An example:**

I want to open 2 tabs of my page, both of them should be able to show the data of two different accounts. E.g. gmail has the ability to swap between 2 logged in pages. And even if you refresh the tab, the visible account stays the same.

At the moment I have only one possible solution in mind:

> 1. Store the value in the url
> 2. Make sure that every link on this page pass this value to the next page

But this way seems to be a little bit "dirty". It gets broken if I miss a single link.

Is there a way to use a hidden input instead, or some other js features?

Btw: I'm using aspx and IIS as web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use cookie, they stored in browser and stay after reload.
[Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Comment: And how can I detect from which browser window they come? As much as I know, all windows uses the same cookies (within a browser)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14196739/957950)):

> The read-only sessionStorage property accesses a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.
>
> - Whenever a document is loaded in a particular tab in the browser, **a unique page session gets created and assigned to that particular tab. That page session is valid only for that particular tab.**
> - A page session lasts as long as the tab or the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.
>   **Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context**, which differs from how session cookies work.
> - Opening **multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage for each tab/window**.
> - Duplicating a tab copies the tab's sessionStorage into the new tab.
> - Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.
>
> Data stored in sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page. In particular, data stored by a script on a site accessed with HTTP (e.g., http://example.com) is put in a different sessionStorage object from the same site accessed with HTTPS (e.g., https://example.com).
>
> The keys and the values are always in the UTF-16 string format, which uses two bytes per character. As with objects, integer keys are automatically converted to strings.

Those last 2 bullet points suggest some additional edge cases that may make `sessionState` testing and isolation very tricky for some usage requirements.