# Search query tracking from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-tag-manager, addeventlistener

On `www.mypage.com` i have an iframe with `www.search.mypage.com`. Both parent frame and iframe have a GTM container I have access to.
When a search is made in the iframe, the iframe GTM container sends a message to the parent frame, with the data. This message is picked up by a `eventlistener` in the parent frame, parsed and pushed to the DL (`datalayer` of the parent frame).

But when the user refines the search term, a new message is send. I want to be able to store these search terms done in the same session, in an `Array` to be pushed to the `datalayer`, so I can see see the refinement done be the user of the session.

Example:

1. search: `[term1]`
2. search: `[term1, term2]`
3. search: `[term1, term2, term3]`

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved? 
I have the following event listener attached to the parent frame, that listens for an event, `iframeSearchSubmit`.

[event listener added to window on first page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXnbJ.png)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window) {
    
        addEvent(window, 'message', function(message) {
          
          try{
            
           var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
           var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || (window.dataLayer = []);
          
          
           if (data.event) {
            
             dataLayer.push({
               'event': data.event,
               'postMessageData': data,
               'query': data.query
            });
          } 
            
         }catch(e){}
          
        });
        
        // Cross-browser event listener
        function addEvent(el, evt, fn) {
          if (el.addEventListener) {
            el.addEventListener(evt, fn);
          } else if (el.attachEvent) {
            el.attachEvent('on' + evt, function(evt) {
              fn.call(el, evt);
            });
          } else if (typeof el['on' + evt] === 'undefined' || el['on' + evt] === null) {
            el['on' + evt] = function(evt) {
              fn.call(el, evt);
            };
          }
        }
    
    })(window);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **I want to be able to store these search terms done in the same session**

The dataLayer has a page scope, ie whenever the page is reloaded it gets cleared, so that won't work. **Thus you need to add some form of persistence yourself**, a few options:

- **[Session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196671/session-only-cookies-with-javascript)**
- **[Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**
- **[Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)** which you would clear at the start of each session
- **[Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)** which abstracts the session and local storage
- **[IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)** which is a client-side DB, to clear upon start of session

Because **browser support can vary and coding can be a bit heavy**, you might want to look at libraries which wrap/abstract those storage options so you can write a more robust implementation with less code:

- https://github.com/localForage/localForage
- https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/
- https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb
- https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb
- https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval

Here is an example showing how to persist GTM data layer:

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/two-ways-to-persist-data-via-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look on which storage will be best suited.