# Make cookies never expire with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am using angularjs cookies.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

I am using `$cookies` to store username and password. I know that is bad practice but put that aside for the moment. I want the user to log in once and never need to do it again unless the cookies are cleared. However, the problem is that after the chrome browser is closed, the user has to log in again next time he visits the web page because the cookies are no longer present. I want the cookies to never expire.

Here is the relevant code written in a factory;

```
.factory('AuthenticationService',
        ['$base64', '$http', '$cookies', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'configuration',
            function ($base64, $http, $cookies, $rootScope, $timeout, $configuration) {

                var service = {};

                service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {
                    //login code
                };

                service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
                    var authdata = $base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

                    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; 
                    $cookies.put('username', username);
                    $cookies.put('authdata', authdata);
                };

                return service;
            }])
```

How to make the cookies to never expire and remain there even after the browser is closed?

Answer (score 2):

from what I have read you can't really set it to **never** expire - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/532638/669664

the best solution I came up with is to set it to a date in the future - but be conscious of the 2038 bug for *nix systems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

using Angular 1.4+ - make use of the `$cookiesProvider` options:

```
            var expireDate = new Date();
            expireDate.setTime(2144232732000);
            if (thisIsAValue=== undefined) {
                $cookies.putObject("thisIsYourCookieObject", {
                    "foo": 1,
                    "bar": 1
                }, {'expires': expireDate});
            }
```

I know this is an old post - I hope this might help someone.