# Longest possible cookie expiration date?

Tags: javascript, cookies

this is my first post but I was a little unclear about formatting after reading the other posts about this. Below is my Javascript code, I am trying to set the longest possible expiration date.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
  var expires = "expires=" + new Date(2147483647 * 1000).toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Is this correct?

Do I put:

```
"expires=" + new Date(2147483647 * 1000).toUTCString();
```

or just

```
 "expires=" + "2147483647";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Cookie with no expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532635/javascript-cookie-with-no-expiration-date)

Comment: Not really, updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The latest possible date is so far into the future you probably wouldn't want that!

```
let maxDate = new Date(8640000000000000).toUTCString();
console.log(maxDate);

//Result:
Sat, 13 Sep 275760 00:00:00 GMT
```

Normally, a max date would be 31 Dec 2099

Comment: This is crazy old but the timestamp for Thu 31 Dec 2009 23:59:59 is 4102444799000 for all of you copy-and-pasters.