Persist session (cookies) in react-native-webview with rails
I'm trying to keep my users logged in when they re-open the app after closing it.
I use ruby on rails on the server and react native with react-native-webview on the mobile side.
It's only on iOS right now but would like to make it for Android as well.
Here is what I tried:
      sharedCookiesEnabled={true}

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                                       key: '_code_session',
                                       domain: :all / "dev.codedorian.com", 
                                       secure: true / false, 
                                       httponly: true / false, 
                                       same_site: :strict / :lax / :none

Here is my webview:
    <WebView
      onMessage={onMessage}
      ref={webViewRef}
      source={{uri: CODE_URL}}
      onLoadStart={update}
      onLoad={update}
      onLoadEnd={update}
    />

(the updates might be overkill)

Did you try expires_after? https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

yeah thanks @max that works :) I tried nil but didn't seem to work, so I did 1.year and that worked

nil would mean that there is no expiry set so that the cookie is deleted as soon as the browser session ends (the window closes).

The solution, with the help from @max was:
config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 1.year

in config/application.rb
I just set an arbitrary high value because I don't want my users to be logged out, not sure what's the min and max or if some kind of nil expire_after would be possible

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532635/javascript-cookie-with-no-expiration-date
